# What is wrong with DateValidator?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have an  activerecord model where I have next rule:
`['birthdate','date','format'=>'php:Y-m-d'],`

and component with next code:

```
class UserTime extends Component{

    public function update() {

    if(!\Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        $user=User::find()->where(['id'=>  \Yii::$app->user->id])->one();
        $last_visit=new \DateTime($user->last_visit);
        $last_visit=$last_visit->getTimestamp();
        $now=new \DateTime(date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
        $now=$now->getTimestamp();
        $diff=$now-$last_visit;
        if($diff<600){
        $user->total_time+=$diff;

        }
        $user->last_visit=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
        $user->save();

    }


}

}
```

The problem here is that the component does not work properly and does not save changes to database when the above validating rule is active. But it works when the rule is removed. I don't have any idea how to fix this problem.

Comment: Are you adding a validator against the birthdate property? I don't see birthdate being populated there in your example

Comment: I'm not populating it, it's already populated. I just need to change the `last_visit` and `total_time` columns but somehow `date` validator don't let me do that.